# Is Spring Security Remember Me will work after server was restarted?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am totally a newbie in Spring Security. I am getting start from [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-remember-me) example for spring security *Remember Me*. It is fine. But I don't understand why I login again after server has restarted. I used [TokenBasedRememberMeServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.html)  and I don't want to use [PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.html).

I think `<sec:remember-me key="myKey" token-validity-seconds="604800" use-secure-cookie="true"/>` may be valid until cookie has been expired even server *(Tomcat)* has restarted. Please somebody help me what am I wrong ?

Comment: Are you using Tomcat? Have you configured it correctly for session persistence accross restarts?

Comment: @geoand Please guide me sir how ?

Comment: Check out http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html

Comment: @geoand sir ! can you give me short configuration please ? I don't know what configuration must be put. I really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: I haven't performed the configuration myself, but from what you are describing it sounds like Tomcat is not persisting the session when shutting down. The link I provided is for confifuring `${TOMCAT_HOME}/conf/context.xml`.

Comment: Tomcat persistent sessions are irrelevant. Remember-me is based on cookies and should work through a server restart.

Answer (score 1):

Remember-me should work after a restart. Most likely you are sending the request over an insecure connection (HTTP), but you have set `use-secure-cookie` to true, which means the cookie will only be sent over HTTPS. Hence the browser doesn't send the cookie and the server doesn't log the user in. You should use an HTTPS connection to your server.

You should be able to debug this by monitoring the requests and responses sent by your browser (always a good idea).